# using javascript show different forms on buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a form where i have two buttons and i want to show data from database on one button and want to show a form on second button. This code is working but show the same form on whatever i click. Kindly help me with this thankyou!!

```
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Survey" />
  <script language="javascript">
    function check(form) {
      window.open('index.html')
    }
  </script>

  <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="detail" />

  <script language="javascript">
    function check(form) {

      window.open('databasedetail.php')
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: change second function name to check2

Comment: thankyou sir!! my problem is solve now.. thankyou very much!! @PrashanthReddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some logic and structure errors. Try something more like the following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="check('survey');return false" value="Survey" />
<input type="button" onclick="check('detail');return false" value="detail" />

<script language="javascript">
function check(mode) {
    var pageToOpen;
    if (mode == 'survey') {
        pageToOpen = 'index.html';
    } else if (mode == 'detail') {
        pageToOpen = 'databasedetail.php';
    }
    if (pageToOpen) {
        window.open(pageToOpen);
    }
}
</script>
```